# Which Machine Learning Algorithm to Look into?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, algorithms, pattern-recognition

I have tried googling and couldn't find much of relevance so I have come here to ask.

In essence, I want to know which machine algorithm can be used to (well, to some extent) detect repeating patterns in say a scatter plot of data (as seen below):

[image: Bad Example]

So I have highlighted with black outlined boxes what I would expect the algorithm to detect - two or more very similar patterns. Are there any algorithms that are able to do such a thing? It would be nice if there was a ready to go Python module so I can readily apply the algorithm to my data, short on time!

Comment: If you know the pattern you are looking for, then convolving with a template of the pattern can be used to detect its presence, this is how convolutional neural networks work.  But how to detect any kind of general phenomena that exists a few times in a series of data is a difficult question to solidify.  What is a pattern?  For example, there are *three* examples of "a few points in a row decrease" in your series, but you did not highlight them, why?

Comment: @MatthewDrury Thanks for replying. I don't know what pattern I am looking for unfortunately. I see your final point...I didn't think to this depth. Ugh.

Comment: @MatthewDrury My line of thinking was that, in a set of generally random data, any patterns that repeats may be able to get picked up (since these patterns occur more frequently than say those 3 dots)?

Comment: Are you looking for something that repeats with some regularity, like a seasonal trend? You could try Fourier decomposition and look for frequencies with large magnitudes if that's the case.

Comment: @KMcC Thanks, I have around 5 million points of data, do you think I will be computationally limited?

Comment: I don't know. I've never run a Fourier analysis on that large a dataset and I don't actually know how well it scales.

Comment: It's hard to give an answer that will for sure do what you want, but try a convolutional autoencoder. This will generate kernels that contain the most relevant patterns in your data for reconstructing it. Then you can slide these kernels over new inputs and get a mapping of exactly where each of these patterns appear at.

Comment: Try clustering your timeseries. Cluster may be the typical patterns.